# Using enums in jQuery grid

Tags: c#, jquery, datagrid

I'm using datagrid with ExtJs.net

I bind an object to the store which contains member of enum type:

```
enum Colors 
{
    red,
    yellow,        
    black,
    brown
}
```

and where the enum type is loaded in the grid ->

```
{ 
    header: "colors",
    width: 170,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'colors',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        allowBlank: true
    }
},
```

When the grid is loaded up it displays just numbers, `2,3,1` for example instead of "red", "yellow" or "black"

How can I print out enums values as a string?

Comment: Hi agh, how did you ended up with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return them as a string from your C# code, i.e. `red.ToString()`. Otherwise the value of the enum will be displayed, as you discovered.